# How does the Swift Dictionary subscript disambiguate Int keys and indices?

Tags: swift, dictionary, ambiguous, subscript

Currently I'm working on a data structure intended to store store key-value pairs uniquely and keep them sorted by key. Essentially it is a sorted dictionary and as such I am seeking to keep as much of the Collection and Dictionary semantics of Swift as I can.

In the documentation and Swift source (as best as I can find), Dictionaries have two subscripts. One is the most commonly used [subscript by key (Github source)](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/48a8b2655a81bde972c139246ad024b55026a8cb/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L2077-L2092):

```
extension Dictionary {
  ...
  public subscript(key: Key) -> Value? {
    @inline(__always)
    get {
      return _variantBuffer.maybeGet(key)
    }
    set(newValue) {
      if let x = newValue {
        // FIXME(performance): this loads and discards the old value.
        _variantBuffer.updateValue(x, forKey: key)
      }
      else {
        // FIXME(performance): this loads and discards the old value.
        removeValue(forKey: key)
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

And the second is a [subscript by position/index (Github) source)](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/48a8b2655a81bde972c139246ad024b55026a8cb/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L2026-L2028) as part of its conformance to the Collection protocol:

```
extension Dictionary: Collection {
  ...
  public subscript(position: Index) -> Element {
    return _variantBuffer.assertingGet(position)
  }
  ...
}
```

When using these with a Dictionary keyed by something other than an `Int`, they behave exactly as expected because the subscripts are distinguished by different parameter types, ie: `String` vs `Int`.

```
let stringKeys = ["One": 1, "Two": 2, "Three": 3]
stringKeys["One"]   // 1
stringKeys[1]       // ("Two", 2)
```

When `Int`s are used as keys, the key subscript is used as desired.

```
let intKeys = [1: "One, 2: "Two, 3: "Three"]
intKeys[1]   // "One"
```

How does the Dictionary type accomplish this? It would seem to me that the `Index` and `Key` parameters of the subscripts are both `Int` and that the compiler should not know which was intended.  Indeed, when I implement the same subscripts for my custom dictionary, the compiler gives exactly that error—"Ambiguous use of 'subscript'"—when I test it with `Int` keys.

At first I wondered if one was a default provided in a protocol extension and overridden by a more specific implementation, but from what I can tell above that is not the case. The only other theory I have is that `Index` is of some other type than 'Int` such that it remains unambiguous but I can't find my way to anything that confirms this. Can anyone shed some light on this? Beyond my immediate needs, it's quite a clever bit of behavior in Swift that I'd like to understand.

Thank you to all for reading and for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> The only other theory I have is that Index is of some other type than 'Int` such that it remains unambiguous but I can't find my way to anything that confirms this.

That's exactly how it is. `Dictionary` has two subscript methods:

```
public subscript(key: Dictionary.Key) -> Dictionary.Value?
public subscript(position: Dictionary<Key, Value>.Index) -> Dictionary.Element { get }
```

The first one takes a key and returns an (optional) value,
the second one takes a [`Dictionary.Index`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary.index)
([source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/48a8b2655a81bde972c139246ad024b55026a8cb/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L5993))
and returns an (optional) [`Dictionary.Element`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/element),
i.e. a key-value pair.
Example:

```
let d : Dictionary = [1 : "one"]
if let idx = d.index(forKey: 1) {
    print(String(reflecting: type(of: idx))) // Swift.Dictionary<Swift.Int, Swift.String>.Index
    let kv = d[idx]
    print(String(reflecting: type(of: kv)))  // (key: Swift.Int, value: Swift.String)
}
```

`Dictionary.Index` is also used in other methods such as

```
public var startIndex: Dictionary<Key, Value>.Index { get }
public var endIndex: Dictionary<Key, Value>.Index { get }
public func index(where predicate: ((key: Key, value: Value)) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Dictionary<Key, Value>.Index?
```

which are part of the `Collection` protocol.

Generally, the associated `Index` type of a `Collection` is not
necessarily an `Int`, another example is `String` which has its
own `String.Index` type.