# Dictionary subscript by index

Tags: swift, dictionary

In [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/subscript(_:)-4bhoo) there is an explanation that a dictionary can be subscripted by using the `Index` of the `Key` of the dictionary. I was looking at this, but this doesn't seem to work for me. Given the following example:

```
enum CustomKey: String, Hashable {
    case a, b, c
}

struct CustomValue {}

func test() {
    let dictionary = [CustomKey: [CustomValue]]()

    // This compiles just fine
    var values = dictionary[.a]

    // No exact matches in call to subscript
    var indexed = dictionary[0]
}
```

As far as I know, I have the `Key` conform to `Hashable` as per requirement, yet I am not able to use an integer as subscript, why not?

Comment: The documentation link to `subscript` you reference shows that the position parameter is of type `Dictionary<Key, Value>.Index`, not `Int`. That's why you can't pass `0`.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47724891/1187415

Comment: @MartinR yeah, I read that post. But I was wondering why this "out of the box" behaviour seems to not work in my scenario? What am I missing? I.e. why can I not get the _nth element_ of the dictionary the same way as how I access an array? And also, why does a `.forEach` work on a dictionary then?

Comment: "I.e. why can I not get the nth element of the dictionary the same way" For the reason that I gave in my answer; there is no stable, meaningful "nth element". "And also, why does a .forEach work on a dictionary then?" For the reason that I gave in my answer: the built-in higher-order functions cycle through the dictionary for you, in no particular order (which is exactly what would happen if you ran the `for i in` code in my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing?

You're assuming that "index" necessarily means "integer index". This is not the case.

Every [`Collection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection) has its own [`Index`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/index) in Swift. An *index* for a collection is something which given to that collection's [subscript operator (`[]`)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/subscript(_:)-887tm) to retrieve a value in constant time (`O(1)`).

You're used to `Array`, whose `Index` is just an `Int`, but that's a special case. You can imagine for a linked list, an `Int` won't do you any good for getting a value in constant time. A linked list might be implemented with a custom `Index` type, whose value just points to one of the `Node`'s. The subscript operator can just jump right into that node, and pull out the value.

Other common collections define their own special index types, `Dictionary` being one of them:

1. [`String.Index`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/index)
2. [`Set.Index`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/index)
3. [`Dictionary.Index`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/index)

> I.e. why can I not get the nth element of the dictionary the same way as how I access an array?

Because Dictionaries are inheritently unordered. `Dictionary` is backed by a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), a data structure that provides fast access to elements by arbitrary key, but which has no way of preserving the order of elements. To support ordering, `Dictionary` would need to add a second auxillary data store, which stores the order of keys (such an `Array` or linked list). Storing this auxillary data store would make Dictionaries take more memory, and it would need to be updated on every change to a dictionary, making it take more CPU time. Because of these trade-offs, the default `Dictionary` doesn't do it by default.

The official [`swift-collections`](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections) package does have an implementation of exactly this: [`OrderedDictionary`](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md)

Answer (score 1):

For

```
var indexed = dictionary[0]
```

Write instead

```
var indexed = dictionary[dictionary.startIndex]
```

To cycle through all the elements of `dictionary` by index, you could say, for instance:

```
for i in 0..<dictionary.count {
    print(dictionary[dictionary.index(dictionary.startIndex, offsetBy: i)])
}
```

Note, however, that accessing a dictionary's values by index is not only likely but pretty much guaranteed to be useless, as there is no stable order: the correspondence between the order of indices and the elements in the dictionary is not only random but is randomized differently every time the code compiles. To put it another way, a dictionary has no meaningful / useful first element; the `for i in` code can give a different output every time. It is more common to use built-in higher-order functions such as `map` (or `mapValues`) that cycle through the dictionary for you (in no particular order).